# How to GET the value of an attribute ID?

Tags: jquery, ajax

e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="edit-product-20">EDIT</button>
```

I have a buttons with dynamic ID's , for above example i want to get only the "20". Can I do that? Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all elements with dynamic id in your case use `$('[id^="edit-product-"]')` to select all elements with id starts with `edit-product-` .

See this example using `.split` and `.pop()` with pure js `.id`.

```js
//using each without events
$('[id^="edit-product-"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.id.split("-").pop());
});

//OR

//get number on click
$('[id^="edit-product-"]').click(function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(this.id.split("-").pop());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="edit-product-20">EDIT 20</button>
<button type="button" id="edit-product-21">EDIT 21</button>
<button type="button" id="edit-product-22">EDIT 22</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Bro @Mamdouh.. its working now, sorry for my very nonsense question. I'm new in AJAX and also select a select just like you did _id^="edit-product-"]_. Thank you again Bro

Comment: You are welcome @Marky :)  just apply changes in your question and accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: What do you want to know? you want to get number on click or styling buttons based on id ? or ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($('#edit-product-20').attr('id').split('-')[2])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="edit-product-20">EDIT</button>
```

Use `.split()`

> The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Comment: Sorry sir if my question is nonsense, But "20" is dynamic. It's displayed from database.